# GET method in form returns wrong URL

Tags: html, forms, get

I have a simple form with `method="get"` and `action="?subject=search_result&"`:

```html
<form class="form" id="searchform" name="searchform" action="?subject=search_result&" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>                            
</form>
```

it only return

> ?search=blablabla

instead of

> ?subject=search_result&search=blablabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
<form class="form" id="searchform" name="searchform" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="search_result">                         
</form>
```

Notice the `<input type="hidden"`. This will give you both `search` and `search_result` inside your URL.

Comment: @stacheldraht27 no worries - you can do this for multiple parameters with multiple `<input type="hidden"` tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hidden input field to set the extra parameters and you can remove the action attribute. The default method is GET, that can also be avoided as shown below:-

```html
<form class="form" id="searchform" name="searchform">
   <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="search_result">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>                            
</form>
```